# Is there a way to find all the combinations of lists of lists that do not share any item?

Tags: python, list

I have my data in the form of a list of lists of lists; each item in the main list is a pair of quartets of strings like `[['compasso', 'mail', 'coscia', 'nuotata'], ['braciola', 'pianto', 'violino', 'bevuta']]`, so that the whole list looks like this:

```
[[['compasso', 'mail', 'coscia', 'nuotata'],
  ['braciola', 'pianto', 'violino', 'bevuta']],
 [['compasso', 'pianto', 'racchetta', 'chiamata'],
  ['cornetto', 'fumata', 'femore', 'serenata']],
 [['fagiolo', 'frustata', 'racchetta', 'sussurro'],
  ['foglia', 'urlo', 'cappello', 'complimento']],
   ...
 [['kit-kat', 'trailer', 'piffero', 'ovazione'],
  ['gessetto', 'esplosione', 'ocarina', 'complimento']]]
```

I have to find a way to build all the possible lists of lists of lists where no string appears more than one time, that is, where no string is repeated. Or another acceptable outcome would be to find the biggest list of lists of lists that meets this constraint. To be clear, what I need is an output that is a list of lists of lists as the input, but where no string is repeated *at all*; every string should appear only once in the whole nested list in output. Moreover, the output list should keep the same structure of the input list, that is, it should have four items in each inner list. For now, what I did was:

```py
items = set()
unique = []
for octect in octects:
    quartet1, quartet2 = octect
    if set(quartet1+quartet2).isdisjoint(items):
        unique.append(octect)
        for word in quartet1+quartet2:
            items.add(word)
```

Where `octects` is my original list.

Although this solution returns a list where no string is repeated, it is not the biggest combination of the original list's items, and of course it gives me only this alternative.

Another option that came to my mind was to iterate over all the `itertools.combinations(octects, n)` and check whether the constraint is met, but this would not be very efficient computationally and I would have to decide *a priori* the number of items in the combination, so not ideal. However, the output I am looking for is of the kind that I would obtain with itertools.combinations: a combination of the original pairs of quartets, where no string is repeated. So a way to obtain that would be:

```py
stimuli = []
for comb in combinations(octects, 40):
    merged = set(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(comb))) # flatten nested list
    if len(merged) == 320: # if len = 320 (8X40), it means that there are no duplicates
        stimuli.append(comb)
        print(comb)
```

But (a) it would not be computationally efficient and (b) I would be specifying the number of items, whitout any way to maximize it.

---

**General example of input**

```
input = [[['a','b','c','d'],
          ['e','f','g','h']], # (1) shares 'a' with 2
         [['a','i','q','r'],
          ['s','t','u','v']], # (2) shares 'a' with 1, 'i' with 3, 'q', 'r', 's', 't' with 4
         [['i','j','k','l'], 
          ['m','n','o','p']], # (3) shares 'i' with 3
         [['q','r','s','t'],
          ['u','v','w','x']]] # (4) shares 'q', 'r', 's', 't' with 2
```

**Output**

The biggest list of lists of lists that I can obtain from such input is this, without (2), that shares items with most lists.

```
output = [[['a','b','c','d'],
           ['e','f','g','h']],
          [['i','j','k','l'], 
           ['m','n','o','p']], 
          [['q','r','s','t'],
           ['u','v','w','x']]]
```

If I was simply iterating as in my first solution, I would have excluded (3) and (4).

---

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I still think you'd need to iterate over `itertools.combinations()`, but one thing you could to do make an easier check is `if not set(quartet1) & set(quartet2)`, since sets have the whole 'no duplicate elements' thing built in and the intersection of sets with no duplicates would be empty. Maybe load just the sets into `itertools.combinations` in the first place, if that works.

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to remove duplicates in the innermost list, if exist right? For example, duplicates in a list like this: ['compasso', 'mail', 'coscia', 'nuotata']. Or you want to combine the two innermost lists to form a single list with uniques?

Comment: @picmate涅 Sorry, I was unclear in my explanation. I want to remove duplicates in the output list of lists of lists: no word should appear twice _at all_ after the cleaning, not just in the innermost or intermediate list.

Comment: Ah, ok, got it.

Comment: I posted an answer based on the information you gave and what I understood from that. Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
lll = [[['compasso', 'mail', 'coscia', 'nuotata'],
  ['braciola', 'pianto', 'violino', 'bevuta']],
 [['compasso', 'pianto', 'racchetta', 'chiamata'],
  ['cornetto', 'fumata', 'femore', 'serenata']],
 [['fagiolo', 'frustata', 'racchetta', 'sussurro'],
  ['foglia', 'urlo', 'cappello', 'complimento']]]
```

---

```
import itertools
    
items = set()

for i, ll in enumerate(lll):
    combined_set = set(itertools.chain(*ll))
    if combined_set & items:
        lll.pop(i)
        
items.update(combined_set)
```

---

The inplace deduped original list doesn't contain secondary lists with items that appeared before:

```
print(lll)
    
[[['compasso', 'mail', 'coscia', 'nuotata'],
  ['braciola', 'pianto', 'violino', 'bevuta']],
 [['fagiolo', 'frustata', 'racchetta', 'sussurro'],
  ['foglia', 'urlo', 'cappello', 'complimento']]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, this is not what I aimed for (I edited the question, my fault). The output should have all the inner lists of length 4; so for the example you used in your answer it would be either a list with the first and the third sublists, where the second list of lists is not included since the string 'compasso' is shared with the first list, or a list with the second and the third sublists, where the first one is not included since it shares with the second one the string 'compasso'.

Comment: What you are saying is, if an item appeared before in an inner list, and if that item appears again in a subsequent inner list, the entire parent list (secondary list) that is associated with the list shouldn't appear in the final list correct? I think I got it this time. Can you check the updated answer?

Comment: Yes that is what I am aiming for. However, if I just iterate over the original lll, I don't have any certainty that my output would be the largest unique combination possible. And I think your solution is similar to what I posted in the question (with & and pop instead of isdisjoint() and append())

Comment: For instance, in such an iteration the first octect would be kept by default (since the items set is empty when starting the iteration), but there may be other combinations that do not include the first item and end up being bigger

Comment: So, basically, if there are two internal lists with the same element in it, you want to preserve the one with the most number of elements in the list right? For example, if you have (1) [['compasso', 'mail', 'coscia', 'nuotata'],  ['braciola', 'pianto', 'violino', 'bevuta']] and (2) [['compasso', 'fagiolo', 'frustata', 'racchetta', 'sussurro'],  ['foglia', 'urlo', 'cappello', 'complimento']]; you want to retain list number 2 correct?

Comment: And what about lists with the same number of elements that have one or more common elements? How do you want to break the tie?

Comment: Actually, I would prefer if you can show a ,general case, input and and expected output. Looking at your original data, all the internal lists appear to have only 4 elements, and since you also call octets to the second level lists, I am finding it difficult to understand whether an internal list with more than 4 elements could exist.

Comment: What I am aiming for is the biggest lll that combines the most ll (without modifying them: always ll with length 2, and l with length 4), where no string is repeated. I want the biggest combination of the original lls with no string repetition. Your answer was giving me the desired output for this specific toy example, but it was susceptible to initialization and with bigger lists it would give no certainty to obtain the bigger lll, although its output meets the constraint of no string repetition. I edited the question and added one general example btw